# Kiosk Computer has timeout set in security policy

Tags: windows-10, timeout

I am responsible for a Kiosk computer(Win10) running an Access interface.  I had previously set the power settings and screensaver to never lock the computer, however a recent corporate security policy is enforcing a lockout on all machines.  I do NOT have this computer configured as a Windows 10 kiosk profile because I haven't tested all functionality of the Access app while in kiosk mode.  This computer runs as a normal (non admin) user, and should only reset when it receives an update.

I'm currently using a Chrome plugin that generates some activity to keep the computer from locking, however this adds complexity and confusion for the people responsible for logging in to the machine if it is found to have been reset.

I'm asking for ways to keep this machine from locking when it is not in use.

Comment: "recent corporate security policy is enforcing a lockout on all machines. "  <-- You have to ask your company. We do not have access to your company policies here.

Comment: I'm doing that too.  In the meantime, I guess I'm looking for ways to generate whatever the chrome plugin is doing without having to launch chrome.

Comment: Ask your corporate IT department, we cannot help defeat corporate policies here at SU.

Answer (score 1):

*"I'm doing that too. In the meantime, I guess I'm looking for ways to generate whatever the chrome plugin is doing without having to launch chrome."* - From your comment in the OP.

No matter what, in order to circumvent the inactivity logout, you're going to have to run *something*. If not chrome, then it will just be something else. You could use a simple macro program that starts on logon, like Autohotkey, and have it play a mouse movement in a 2x2 pixel area when the mouse has not recently been moved more than a small distance.

There will not be a way to avoid this in the meantime. You either have to have something creating false activity, or get the policy overridden for that machine.

Edit: Also, I believe it's against the rules here on stack exchange to ask a question such as this, so I won't be providing any more details or clarification to this answer. Sorry.