# Stuck in kiosk mode

Tags: windows-10, kiosk

I created a kiosk user on my corporate laptop as an experiment to see how it would run, and to see if I can use a dedicated computer to run an app at my job.  There are a lot of online guides and I followed them to the letter, but the instructions for how to exit kiosk mode are not working and I can't get back into my profile!

I'm sure now that our (offsite) IT department is managing the UAC, so it isn't working as expected.  I started a help desk chat but they had no idea what to do and escalated it.  My experience with this is that escalations take days to resolve and I'd like to work on this problem on my own.

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise, and following online guides I have tried:

1. Exiting kiosk mode by pressing ctrl-alt-del. There should be an option to login as myself from that screen, but there is not.
2. There is a 'power off' icon in the login screen mentioned in the previous bullet.  According to the guides I mentioned above, holding shift while selecting 'reset' should bring me to a login screen that allows me to login as myself.  It does not, it brings me to a blue recovery screen.  The recovery screen does have an option to open a black command prompt, however. I am hopeful that I can find a way to disable kiosk mode via command prompt.

What can I do to disable kiosk mode from this recovery pane?

EDIT: Commenters have suggested this [link to another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1595550/kiosk-computer-has-timeout-set-in-security-policy) as a possible solution.  This question was asked by myself earlier regarding a completely different issue I was having in configuring a kiosk. The current issue is completely unrelated, the current issue was completely resolved by my answer below.

Comment: Which OS? How you've entered kiosk mode? What you've tried to exit it?....

Comment: Windows 10 enterprise, not sure of the version.  I've tried ctrl-alt-del to get to a login screen and shit-reset to bring up a login with my profile, as directed by the guides I used.  Neither choice gives me my profile as a login option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kiosk Computer has timeout set in security policy](https://superuser.com/questions/1595550/kiosk-computer-has-timeout-set-in-security-policy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get into my profile by holding ***BOTH*** shift keys while resetting the computer.  Doing so brought up the "Login as another user" option at the bottom of the screen and I was able to enter my credentials and login as myself.  I deleted the kiosk user once I was logged in as myself and my machine is back to normal.

This isn't documented anywhere that I found, but it worked for me.  Thank you to anyone who looked for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution is: turn off the computer. Hold down the "Shift" key and turn on the computer. Keep holding the "shift" button until Windows starts. Then the option to sign in with other users will be shown in the lower left corner.

good luck!